# Azure postgres flexible server create user using terraform

Tags: postgresql, azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-postgresql

I am trying to create users with names same as that of the DB in postgres flexible server using terraform. The user creation code is as below.

```
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "create_users" {
  name      = "create_users_script"
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example.id
  count     = length(var.db_names)
  value     = <<-EOT
    CREATE USER ${var.db_names[count.index]} WITH PASSWORD 'password1';
  EOT
}
```

Everything seems good with terraform plan, with it showing the names of users to be created like:

```
  # module.eng_dev_pg.azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration.create_users[0] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "create_users" {
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "create_users_script"
      + server_id = "/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/rsg-01/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/pg-02"
      + value     = <<-EOT
            CREATE USER keycloak WITH PASSWORD 'password1';
        EOT
    }
```

But while terraform apply, it errors out saying:

> Error: updating Configuration (Subscription: "XXXXX"
> Resource Group Name: "rsg-01"
> Flexible Server Name: "pg-02"
> Configuration Name: "create_users_script"): performing Update: unexpected status 400 with error: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid value given for parameter serverParameterValue. Specify a valid parameter value.
> │
> with module.eng_dev_pg.azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration.create_users[0],
> on ../../modules/postgres/public-postgres-flexible.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "create_users":
> 43: resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "create_users" {

I tried a bit of like using for_each, but that's of no use as the current code is polling the required usernames properly as expected.

Expectation is to get the users created; about 12 users to be created.
Error is the same for all user creations.

As the error says `Invalid value given for parameter serverParameterValue` I am looking for a way to specify the `serverParameterValue`.

NOTE: The db_names (user names) are provided from a module as:

```
db_names = ["keycloak", "provisioner", "account-development", "customer1-account-development", "customer1-file-development", "customer1-keycloak-development", "customer1-metadata-development", "entity-development", "file-development", "keycloak-development", "provisioner-development", "metadata-development"]
}
```

Comment: The `azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration` sets a PostgreSQL configuration value on the server. It is not intended to run PostgreSQL commands. Per the Terraform documentation, "name" is supposed to specify the name of a PostgreSQL configuration option. You will need to use Venkat V's answer to run the command within Terraform. If using in a DevOps pipeline, then you can run the Azure CLI commands as a separate step if needed. PostgreSQL documentation on server configuration options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html

Answer (score 0):

> Azure postgres flexible server create user using terraform

As the `postgresql flexible server configuration` module is failing during the execution of `terraform apply` for creating users in `PostgreSQL` flexible database.

Alternatively, you can use `Azure CLI` commands within a null resource in Terraform.

Here is the updated code to create multiple users in a `PostgreSQL flexible` server database.

```kotlin
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "postgreysql-resources-demo1"
  location = "eastasia"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "example" {
  name                   = "venkatflexibleserver5"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                = "12"
  administrator_login    = "psqladmin"
  administrator_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
   zone                   = "1"


  storage_mb = 32768

  sku_name = "GP_Standard_D4s_v3"

  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.example]
}


resource "null_resource" "execute_az_cli" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      az postgres flexible-server connect -n "venkatflexibleserver5" -u "psqladmin" -p "H@Sh1CoR3!" -d "postgres"
      pwsh -Command "\$usernames = @('keycloak', 'provisioner', 'account_development', 'customer1_account_development', 'customer1_file_development', 'customer1_keycloak_development', 'customer1_metadata_development', 'entity_development', 'file_development', 'keycloak_development', 'provisioner_development', 'metadata_development'); foreach (\$user in \$usernames) { \$sqlCommand = \"CREATE USER \$user WITH PASSWORD 'Welcome@123'\"; az postgres flexible-server execute -n 'venkatflexibleserver5' -u 'psqladmin' -p 'H@Sh1CoR3!' -d 'postgres' -q \$sqlCommand --output table }"
    EOT
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example ]
}
```

**Terraform  Apply:**

[image]

To check all users in a `PostgreSQL database`, Hers is the query.

```sql
    SELECT usename FROM pg_catalog.pg_user;
```

After running the above `Terraform` code, all the **users** specified in the script have been created in the database

[image]

**Reference**: [az postgres flexible-server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/postgres/flexible-server?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Hi bittus,  I hope the posted solution is helpful to resolve the issue.